# Resolve issue with creating and running a jar file in IntelliJ java. Error: Could not find or load main class TestJar

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have created a main class (TestJar) and two addition classes which run from the main. I can run the application from IntelliJ with no issues but when I build and run the jar file if fails.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -jar D:\Data\JavaPGMS\TestJar\out\artifacts\TestJar_jar\TestJar.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class TestJar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestJar

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I was able to create the jar file and run it up until I added the code in one class file which includes the apache.poi library.

Comment: how are you trying to run it? What does your class look like? What does your manifest file look like?

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem with JavaFX exporting. You can export your library with project (fat jar using gradle/maven) or declare path to library in VM options.

Comment: your own main class not being found has not much to do with dependencies